# Need good jquery multiselect plugin with predictive search feature

Tags: jquery

Can you recommend best jQuery multiselect plugin. I need predictive search feature as well with the multiselect. Predictive search feature would be handy because dropdown contains long list of values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) controls toolkit.

Comment: Tried this and found it very helpful - Thank you

Comment: It's very good but not so much accessible for screen reader. I'd prefer some checkboxes version

Answer (score 1):

You should try JQuery UI Multiselect http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/
(It is not maintained by the Jquery UI team)

Comment: This is helpful but 'http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/' fits my need best. Thank you

Comment: That multiselect is a little hard to use and is getting antiquated with its forced dimensions. Very hard to implement in a modern, responsive site.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)

Edit: Second link is removed due to 404 found.

Comment: Given link is not available. Please acknowledge (2nd link).

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, if you are using bootstrap you can use this jquery plugin:

https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: Was using this one for long time but it's kind of buggy and heavy for performance. At the time you couldn't have more than 1000 items. Also it's impossible to use with screen reader unfortunately. Completely not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one and I'm very happy with it (jquery + bootstrap)
[bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)